# Jquery is skipping my if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a equation calculator. All I want it to do is to alert if there is a "C" value input because I want to do something else if there is a "C" value. Even if there is a "C" value it gives me the result. Please help.

```
$('#resultButton').click(function() {
    var cValue = $("#cText").val();
    if (cValue == ""){
        var aValue = $("#aText").val();
        var bValue = $("#bText").val();
        var result = Math.sqrt((aValue*aValue)+(bValue*bValue));
        $('#result').text(result);
    }
    else {
        alert('There is a C value');
    }
});
```

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"All I want it to do is to alert if there is a "C" value input"*

I guess you forgot to include jQuery or something's wrong with your HTML (which you didn't provide).

See, it works perfectly with minimal HTML:

```js
$('#resultButton').click(function() {
    var cValue = $("#cText").val();
    if (cValue == ""){
        var aValue = $("#aText").val();
        var bValue = $("#bText").val();
        var result = Math.sqrt((aValue*aValue)+(bValue*bValue));
        $('#result').text(result);
    }
    else {
        alert('There is a C value');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cText">
<button id="resultButton">Click</button>
```